# How to deal with posts in different languages?

Tags: discussion

On Ask Different, we occasionally get posts in a language other than English. Take the second answer on [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18490/iphoto-does-not-open-a-window-after-lion-upgrade/35911#35911) as an example.

Part of it is in English, the other in Spanish. I don't see the value in having the Spanish there, as the question was asked in English, and this site is based in English.

So what do we do with these posts, and with posts that are *entirely* in another language? Do we translate them? Delete them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are an increasing number of sites on Stack Exchange for other languages. Ask Different is an English site and as such all posts should be in English.

- When a post is solely in a different language, it should be translated to English. The post should then be dealt with as usual.
- When a translation to a different language is given such as that in the linked answer, the different language should be edited out.